# Where can I find known working bugs with Leaflet maps?

Tags: leaflet, limits

I am running into an issue with adding A LOT of markers to the leaflet map. After a few thousand markers are added, they don't even show up anymore. Where can I find known limitations for leaflet?

Answer (score 4):

The question [Maximum number of SVG elements for the browser in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701491/maximum-number-of-svg-elements-for-the-browser-in-a-map) has some good answers.  Basically, the number of markers you can display depends on the user's computer and browser and, if the data is coming from a server, the server's processing power.  I'm not sure if there is a place that documents known limitations.

Usually if you have over 1000 points to show, you simplify things by using a plugin called [Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) which groups the elements.  Or you can use [Heatcanvas](https://github.com/sunng87/heatcanvas) or [Heatmap](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html).

Or if you really need to show all the points, one of the answers to the above question mentions pre-processing things and generating your own tiles.  Then you serve those as an overlay on the Leaflet map.