# How to zoom faster in a SVG drawing with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on a project with D3.js that displays regions of interest (ROI) which are `<g>` elements with one `<polygon>` and one `<text>`. I noticed that zooming becomes very slow when there are a lot of ROI and it seems that this is mostly because of the texts, i.e. when they are hidden with `display: none`, zoom is much faster. The zoom speed is different in every browser: Firefox is quite fast, Chrome is average and Edge is slow.

I tried to speed up the text rendering by using the CSS property `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;` but the difference is marginal. I noticed that some fonts are faster to render than others. Currently the best results I obtained is by using `font-family: monospace;`.

So my question is: How to zoom faster in an SVG drawing with D3? Is there a font that is known to be faster to render than others? Or is there a CSS, SVG or D3 trick that could help?

You can test the zoom speed with the snippet. If you click on the button, the text will be hidden an zooming will be much faster.

```js
"use strict";

// Create data with this structure:
// DATA = [{ name: "", coords: [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]}]
var nbPolyX = 100;
var nbPolyY = 50;
var sqSize = 800 / nbPolyX;
var DATA = [];
for (let idY = 0; idY < nbPolyY; idY++) {
    for (let idX = 0; idX < nbPolyX; idX++) {
        DATA.push({
            name: "x" + idX + "y" + idY,
            coords: [
                idX * sqSize + 1, idY * sqSize + 1,
                (idX + 1) * sqSize - 1, idY * sqSize + 1,
                (idX + 1) * sqSize - 1, (idY + 1) * sqSize - 1,
                idX * sqSize + 1, (idY + 1) * sqSize - 1
            ]
        })
    }
}

var SVGELEM = {};
var ZOOMER = {};
var TRNSF = {
    k: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var ZOOMER = {};
var GZOOM = {};
var ROI = {};
var POLY = {};
var TXT = {};
var BUTTON = {};

addButton();
addSVG();

function addSVG() {

    ZOOMER = d3
        .zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.9, 40])
        .on("zoom", function () {
            onZoom();
        });

    SVGELEM = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", nbPolyX * sqSize)
        .attr("height", nbPolyY * sqSize)
        .call(ZOOMER);

    GZOOM = SVGELEM.append("g");

    ROI = GZOOM.selectAll("g")
        .data(DATA)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("roi", true);

    POLY = ROI.selectAll("polygon")
        .data(function (d) {
            return [d.coords];
        })
        .enter()
        .append("polygon")
        .attr("points", function (d) {
            return d;
        });

    TXT = ROI.selectAll("text")
        .data(function (d) {

            var nbElem = d.coords.length;

            // Polygon mean point X.
            var xMean = 0;
            for (let index = 0; index < nbElem - 1; index += 2) {
                xMean += d.coords[index];
            }
            xMean /= nbElem / 2;

            // Polygon mean point Y.
            var yMean = 0;
            for (let index = 1; index < nbElem; index += 2) {
                yMean += d.coords[index];
            }
            yMean /= nbElem / 2;

            // Return value.
            var ret = {
                name: d.name,
                x: xMean,
                y: yMean
            };
            return [ret];
        })
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });
}

function addButton() {
    BUTTON = d3.select("body").append("button")
        .text("HIDE TEXT")
        .on("click", function btnOnClick() {
            btnOnClick.state = !btnOnClick.state;
            d3.selectAll("text").classed("cl_display_none", btnOnClick.state);
            if (btnOnClick.state) d3.select(this).text("SHOW TEXT");
            else d3.select(this).text("HIDE TEXT");
        });
}

function onZoom() {
    if (d3.event !== null) TRNSF = d3.event.transform;
    GZOOM.attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + TRNSF.x + "," + TRNSF.y + ") scale(" + TRNSF.k + ")"
    );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>SVG ZOOM SPEED</title>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: monospace;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        svg {
            margin: 10px auto;
            border: 1px solid;
            display: block;
        }

        .roi polygon {
            shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
            vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
            fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
            stroke: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

        .roi text {
            text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 1px;
            text-anchor: middle;
            dominant-baseline: middle;
        }

        .cl_display_none {
            display: none;
        }

        button {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 15pt;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>SVG ZOOM SPEED</h3>
    <p>Use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out the SVG drawing then hide the text with the button and observe the speed difference. Test it in different browsers.</p>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="zoom_speed.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to reconsider how many SVG elements you are rendering at once.

Comment: Some comments here might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701491/maximum-number-of-svg-elements-for-the-browser-in-a-map

Comment: Two approaches that have helped me in the past were to only display text after a certain level of zoom, and to only render the groups that would actually fall within the SVG viewport.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ksav. I read the question 18701491 and it is very interesting. If you have a suggestion about the fastest font to render, I would be glad to read that.